# bash Replace column in csv with a substring of that column

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV and in one of the columns I have fields like

```
1. ABD_1&SC;1233;5665;123445
2. 120585_AOP9_AIDMS3&SC;0947;64820;0173
```

I need to replace this column with

```
1. ABD_1
2. AOP9_AIDMS3
```

Essentially from the first alphabetical character (the substring will never start with a numeric value) to the &. I thought I could use a

***regex [a-zA-Z].+?(?=\&)***

and awk to extract the column and replace it, but this is proving beyond my beginner skillset. Iterating over the string in some loop and writing some bash to parse it out is impractical as the file has some 20million+ entries.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If your real data has multiple columns then show multiple columns in your sample input/output. It matters when considering and testing potential solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, assuming you have only one column in your csv (to understand the complete solution below):

## One column

You can use this regex:

```
sed -r 's/^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+[^&;]+).*$/\1/' test.csv
```

Explanations:

- `-r`: use **extended** regular expressions (avoid parenthesis and plus `+` symbol escaping)
- **`^[^a-zA-Z]*`**: **skip** any **non-alpha** characters at the beginning, ...
- **`([a-zA-Z]+[^&;]+)`** ... then **[captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)** at least one **alpha** character followed by a sequence of any character except ampersand `&` and semi-colon `;` ...
- **`.*$`** ... and **skip** any **remaining characters** (if any, they must begin by either an ampersand or a semi-colon since `sed` pattern matching is greedy, i.e. it tries to match the longest sequence) until the end of line ...
- **`\1`** ... and replace the whole matched text (the line since the regex covers it) by the captured sequence.

Working example:

```
$ sed -r 's/^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+[^&;]+).*$/\1/' << 'EOF'
> ABD_1&SC;1233;5665;123445
> 120585_AOP9_AIDMS3&SC;0947;64820;0173
> EOF
ABD_1
AOP9_AIDMS3
```

## Multiple columns:

It looks like you want to process a **specific column**. If you want to process the **`n-th`** column, you can use this regex, which is based on the previous:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]+,){2})[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+[^&;,]+)[^,]*(.*)$/\1\3\4/'
```

- **`^(([^,]+,){<n-1>})`** **captures** the first **`(n-1)th` columns**; replace `<n-1>` by the real value (`0` for the first column works too), and then...
- **`[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+[^&;,]+)`** **captures** **at least one alpha** character **followed** by a sequence of any character **except** ampersand `&`, semi-colon `;` **or a comma**, then ...
- **`[^,]*`** ... **skip** any remaining characters **which are not a comma**  ...
- **`(.*)$`** ... and **captures** columns, basically the **remaining sequence** until the end of line; since any non-comma character was already skipped before, if this sequence exists, it **must begin** with a **comma**; finally ...
- **`\1\3\4/`** ... **replace** the whole matched text (the line since the regex covers it) by the following **captured** sequences:

  - **`\1`** :  the **`(n-1)th` columns** (`\2` is inside)
  - **`\3`** : the text we want to **keep** from the **`n-th`** column
  - **`\4`** : **remaining columns** if any

Working example (it processes the third column):

```
$ sed -r 's/^(([^,]+,){2})[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+[^&;,]+)[^,]*(.*)$/\1\3\4/' << 'EOF'
plaf,plafy,ABD_1&SC;1233;5665;123445,plet
trouf,troufi,120585_AOP9_AIDMS3&SC;0947;64820;0173,plot
EOF
plaf,plafy,ABD_1,plet
trouf,troufi,AOP9_AIDMS3,plot
```